# Move a sprite to touched point increasing velocity the longer the touch

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, physics-engine

How do I move a sprite to touched point on the x axis increasing velocity.x. The longer the touch the higher velocity goes, then when it comes into a certain range of the touch point or the user releases their finger, slow it down again?

I have a player class setup with a velocity value, which is updated in an update method, not sure how to get the required behaviour in the touches methods though?

Cheers,

Lewis

Answer (score 1):

This should get you in the ballpark (the instance variables and adding it to be touchable would be in the init, lemme know if you need that snippet as well):

```
- (BOOL) ccTouchBegan: (UITouch *) touch
            withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    _touchBeganAt = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    _velocityChangeSpeed = 1;
}


 - (void) ccTouchEnded: (UITouch *) touch
            withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    _velocityChangeSpeed = -1;
}

- (void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    velocityThreshold = 1; //? You can tune this
    distanceThreshold = 1; //? Same

    _sprite.velocity += _velocityChangeSpeed;

    //So it comes to a complete stop, as opposed to moving backwards
    if(_sprite.velocity < velocityThreshold)
        _velocityChangeSpeed = 0;

    float distanceFromTouchedPoint = ABS(_sprite.position.x - _touchBeganAt.x);
    if(distanceFromTouchedPoint < distanceThreshold)
        _velocity = 0;
}
```